# How do I fix wrapped faces after Data Transfer UV with nearest face interpolate?

Tags: texturing, uv

So I realized I had screwed the UV map of a prebuilt model up by slicing it in half, then using a mirror modifier. However, I sort of resolved this issue by using data transfer to transfer the UV map with Nearest Face Interpolated. Now I have  faces on the side were wrapped around the island. I have found a temporary solution by splitting the faces and scaling them, but this takes way too long and is a painful process. Furthermore, my model already has some seams on it. Can anyone tell me an efficient solution to fix this issue?
[image]